# Laravel 5.1 logout redirect not working

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller

when I click on logout in my app i get redirected to the Laravel 5 default page. I tried  to switch the url to the login and instead of an error i still get redirected to this default page.
This is the code in my AuthController

```
public function doLogout()
{
    Auth::logout();
    Session::flush();
     return Redirect::to('login');
```

also the logout in my routes.php

```
Route::get('auth/logout', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout');
```

any ideas how to redirect to the login page. thank you

Comment: It looks like your route is not using the doLogout method.

Answer (score 0):

you can use below of class

```
protected $redirectAfterLogout = 'auth/login';
```

"auth/login" is the url you can change, this is for laravel 5

the doc:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication